# How to use Xirsys Hosting in Pubnub Android Example?

Tags: android, pubnub, xirsys

https://github.com/GleasonK/android-webrtc-api

I am a student in Korea. I am working on my school project. I am using example from website above. I'm curious about how to connect my Xirsys hosting server and above example project. I read all about descriptions about Pubnub and Xirsys.

When I make a call between my phones on this example. I can make a call and receive call, but they don't get connected.

This is how it looks like.

[image]

Comment: Did you post to Xirsys forums? And to Kevin Gleason's github repo? Just provide link to this SO thread on their forums.

Comment: what do you mean by post to Xirsys forums? do you have any link to the site?

Comment: I mean Xirsys support but looks like they use SO exclusively. https://xirsys.com/contact/

Comment: @이재영 If you have found the fix for the issue, can you please share it?

Comment: mine is still not working. sorry T.T

Comment: Still stuck with PubNub example ?

Comment: Has anyone reached out to Xirsys? Please let me know if you are getting any errors at all. And this is a very old sample app so could use some upgrading.