# PubBub WebRTC Android Demo is Not Connecting from Android to Android

Tags: webrtc, turn, apprtcdemo, xirsys

When I tried the demo app https://kevingleason.me/AndroidRTC/, it was working as expected.

But when I tried with two android devices, I can make a call and receive call, but they don't get connected. In both devices, its own camera feed is displayed with a text "Connecting...". I tried on both my home Wifi and mobile data 3G. There is no error that I can find in log.

Could anyone help me to resolve the issue please. What is that I am missing here?

I am using the latest code from https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC which already has the Xirsys ICE servers configured. But I noticed that the Xirsys ICE servers is not added in the below line from VideoChatActivity.java, so I also tried adding that **servers** into the PnSignalingParams' constructor, but still facing the same Connecting message only.

```
List<PeerConnection.IceServer> servers = getXirSysIceServers();    
if (!servers.isEmpty()) {      
   this.pnRTCClient.setSignalParams(new PnSignalingParams(servers));      
}
```

Comment: @CraigConover - Thanks for your time. Not exactly I guess. I already checked that SO thread, that differs from my case. In my case, after I receive the call in receiver side, both caller and receiver get their own front camera stream is rendered in their own screen along with a text "Connecting...". (not as blank screen as in the other SO thread). Could you please help me.

Comment: @CraigConover - This issue is also listed in one another thread (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835110/how-to-use-xirsys-hosting-in-pubnub-android-example), but I couldn't find solution in that thread.

Comment: Are you able to follow the messages being sent through the signalling?  Can you see if **offer** and **answer** are being passed?  Also, what candidate types (**typ** param in candidate) is the device sending?

Comment: @LeeSylvester - I think, this issue is occurred to almost everyone https://github.com/GleasonK/AndroidRTC/issues/3 it seems. Since I have lack of time in this project, I didn't want to spend more on this. Now I am looking for alternative/custom signaling solutions. If I find some time later, I will post my observation you asked. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue. It was little tricky. If you see the log, it will show you that the application always execute createOffer method. So both client A and client B will send an offer in same time. You can fix that issue by giving some condition so if the client A give an offer, and the client B will response by give an answer.

To see if any error occurs you can use method `onCreateFailure(String s)` and `onSetFailure(String s)` in PnPeer.java.
Hope this will help.